# Website seems to be infected by JPG:PHPAgent-A [Trj]

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, malware, virus, malware-detection

i am trying to find malware infection in my site (Joomla 1.5.26) but i can not find anything suspicious.

Scanned online in several places as also searched in the filesystem!

Anyone with any ideas why my antivirus (avast) is keeping telling me that the website is infected? Actually it finds JPG:PHPAgent-A [Trj] threat on several images loaded by a specific module (which i have checked for infections!)

Here is a link: http://syroshouse.gr/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3&Itemid=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually these JPG files was infected with malware. For anybody interested:

http://blog.sucuri.net/2013/07/malware-hidden-inside-jpg-exif-headers.html